# How to set an ImageView to match_parent and horizontally scale accordingly?

Tags: xml, android-layout, imageview, android

I have a RelativeLayout in a section of my activity that includes a button and an ImageView. The size of the RelativeLayout is ListPreferredItemHeight and what I would like to do is have the ImageView span from top to bottom of that layout and be scaled accordingly.

Currently, without implementing any scaling attributes, I have this image:

[image]

I achieve this with the following xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/newPrescription_Medication"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/newPrescription_AddMedication"
       android:layout_toStartOf="@id/newPrescription_AddMedication"
       android:text="@string/select_medication"/>

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/newPrescription_AddMedication"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:src="@drawable/add_icon"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, to try and fill the space with the button, I added the following to the ImageView tag:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

[image]

How can I get the entire image to appear, while maintaining its position on the right side of the layout and filling the rest with the button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/newPrescription_Medication"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/newPrescription_AddMedication"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

Comment: This seems to have the same behavior as my first example, just a small image centered in the layout.